# Is it possible to create a list matrix?

Tags: list-view, calendar

Is is possible to display a sharepoint list matrix?

I have table I wish to display as a matrix. The columns (or rows) contain indicate months, and the rows (or columns) indicate departments. The body of the matrix show events for specific departments. Events are the common field for both.

I can use the excel webpart, but I'd also like to make this all easily searchable/filtered in a list. The calendarview doesn't present an acceptable timescale and gantt views aren't preferred.

```
         December2015   January2016   February2016   March2016
Dept1      Dec_Event                    Feb_Event    Mar_Event
Dept2                    Jan_Event
Dept3      Dec_Event     Jan_Event
Dept4
```

Comment: A data view web part lets you format a list in any way you'd like, that might be the route I would go if I were you.